# Multiple markers found at this line

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am writing a spring application and i got the **Multiple marker found at this line error** i have attached a screenshot [image: here]

Comment: make sure you hover your mouse over the individual error, not the icon next to the line number.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```